# Need help understanding Python closures

Tags: python, closures

I have this code:

```
import re

def doReplace(toReplace):
    i = 1
    def chapterReplacer(_):
        result = 'Chapter %i' % i
        i += 1
        return result

    return re.sub('Chapter [a-zA-Z]+', chapterReplacer, test)

test = 'Chapter one Chapter Two Chapter three'
print doReplace(test)
```

when I run it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python26/replace.py", line 13, in <module>
    print doReplace(test)
  File "C:/Python26/replace.py", line 10, in doReplace
    return re.sub('Chapter [a-zA-Z]+', chapterReplacer, test)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, 0).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "C:/Python26/replace.py", line 6, in chapterReplacer
    result = 'Chapter %i' % i
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment
```

I was under the impression that chapterReplacer would capture the local variable i, but that doesn't seem to be happening?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141642/what-limitations-have-closures-in-python-compared-to-language-x-closures?rq=1

Comment: The dupe target is not that helpful here, because this is about nested functions trying to assign to a name from the parent scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `i` a function attribute

```
def doReplace(toReplace):
    chapterReplacer.i = 1
    def chapterReplacer(_):
        result = 'Chapter %i' % chapterReplacer.i
        chapterReplacer.i += 1
        return result

    return re.sub('Chapter [a-zA-Z]+', chapterReplacer, test)
```

**EDIT:** As of python 3, you can use `nonlocal` a la @MartijnPieters 's solution.

Comment: if chapterReplacer is only called within doReplace would it matter?

Comment: @Hans: yes, because every time you run `doReplace` you can get a new `chapterReplacer`. If you put the attribute on `doReplace`, then if you run `doReplace` again, you will be using the same `i`, which is incorrect

Comment: hmm @newacct but you're explicitly resetting the value every time when going into doReplace, so wouldn't it not matter?

Comment: @Hans: it would still matter if you have multiple threads or if the code inside could somehow recursively call `doReplace` or something like that

Comment: And it is subtleties like that that lead to hard-to-trace bugs, and why I do *not* use function attributes for closure-breaking variables!

Answer (score 6):

Nope, and in python 2 you can't at all without resorting to using tricks with mutables:

```
def doReplace(toReplace):
    i = [1]
    def chapterReplacer(_):
        result = 'Chapter %i' % i[0]
        i[0] += 1
        return result

    return re.sub('Chapter [a-zA-Z]+', chapterReplacer, test)
```

Normally, python will only look in the surrounding scope for a variable if it is not being assigned to locally; as soon as the bytecompiler sees a direct assignment (`i = something`) and no `global i` statement to persuade it otherwise, a variable is considered local.

But in the above code we never assign to `i` in the `chapterReplacer` function. Yes, we do change `i[0]` but the value stored in `i` itself, a list, does not change.

In python 3, just use the [`nonlocal` statement](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-nonlocal_stmt) to have python look in it's closure for the variable:

```
def doReplace(toReplace):
    i = 1
    def chapterReplacer(_):
        nonlocal i
        result = 'Chapter %i' % i
        i += 1
        return result

    return re.sub('Chapter [a-zA-Z]+', chapterReplacer, test)
```

Comment: Because you are not re-assinging `i`; only members of `i`. The variable itself happens to be mutable, but because it's direct value (a list) doesn't change, python will look in the surrounding scope.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, if you assign to variable inside a function (even if with a compound assignment operator such as `+=`), that variable is considered local unless specified otherwise by a `global` or `nonlocal` statement.

Answer (score 1):

When compiler sees that variable `i` gets another value inside function `chapterReplacer` it treats it as local, and no 'closure magic' is applied.  If you remove line `i += 1`, your code will run.