# I can't decrement N, but I can use it when evaluating logic. Can someone explain this?

Tags: python

Increment is defined as:

```
def increment(x):
    return x + 1
```

The following works, and spits out a result of 8:

```
def repeated(f, n): 
    def h(x):
        counter = 0
        while counter < n:
            x = f(x)
            counter += 1
        return x
    return h
addthree = repeated(increment,3)
addthree(5)
```

The following code errors and tells me that i am referencing n before assignment:

```
def repeated3(f,n): 
    def h(x):
        total=0
        while n != 0:
            total = f(x) + total
            n -= 1
        return total
    return h
addthree = repeated(increment,3)
addthree(5)
```

why does the error throw when i try to decrement n, even though i am allowed to  use it in the logic statement that precedes it?

Comment: 'h' has not been declared as a variable for "return h".  Do you mean return h(variable) <-- ()=function.  Why are you using 2 functions, one of which does nothing but call the other?

Comment: just to be clear, in the second code block did you mean to writ addthree = repeated3(increment, 3) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first function works as you are not assigning/mutating `n` to a new value, using `n -= 1` you are assigning `n` to a new value so you are creating a local variable `n` not using the `n` from the outer function so you end up with a  `local variable 'n' referenced before assignment` error as `n` is not defined when you use `while n != 0:` in the local scope.

In python3, you can use the `nonlocal` keyword:

```
def repeated3(f, n):
    def h(x):
        nonlocal n
        total = 0
        while n != 0:
            total = f(x) + total
            n -= 1
        return total
    return h
```

If you are using python2 you could  reassign a new variable to point to `n` and use that or use a dict:

```
def repeated3(f,n):
    n = {"n":n}
    def h(x):
        total = 0
        while n["n"] != 0:
            total = f(x) + total
            n["n"] -= 1
        return total
    return h
addthree = repeated3(increment,3)
addthree(5)
```

You could also make it a function attribute:

```
def repeated3(f,n):
    repeated3.n = n
    def h(x):
        total = 0
        while repeated3.n != 0:
            total = f(x) + total
            repeated3.n -= 1
        return total
    return h
addthree = repeated3(increment,3)
```

There are numerous other workarounds but the main point is you can read but not mutate the closure variable and creating `n` in your local scope is going to cause  `n` to become a local variable meaning the `while n != 0` is looking for n in the local scope so you get the `referencing n before assignment:`

Answer (score 3):

When functions are nested, the use of an argument or variable of an outer function in an inner function is called a *closure*.

[Python closures are read only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141642/what-limitations-have-closures-in-python-compared-to-language-x-closures)

So, if you want to use a decrement loop, you will need to copy the repetition argument to a writable local variable.

```
In [10]: def r(f,n):
   ....:     def h(x):
   ....:         total = 0
   ....:         m = n
   ....:         while m!=0:
   ....:             total += f(x)
   ....:             m -= 1
   ....:         return total
   ....:     return h
   ....: 

In [11]: r(increment, 3)(0)
Out[11]: 3
```

This isn't a problem with the previously posted incrementing `repeated()` function code because although there the repetitions argument `n` is also a closure, it is used read-only in a comparison and not written to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass 'n' into h(x), making it local. So you have h(x,n=n).