# Using upper level function's variable

Tags: python, closures

I want to use the `num_samples` variable that I have defined in the `make_averaged` function. When I use the variable in `fun_averaged` it should search it in the scope of its `upper level` function.

```
def make_averaged(fn, num_samples=1000):
    def fun_averaged(*args) :
        totalave = 0
        savenum = num_samples
        while not num_samples == 0:
            totalave = fn(*args) + totalave
            num_samples -= 1
        avetagevalue = totalave/savenum
        return avetagevalue
    return fun_averaged
```

However I get an Error

```
    while not samples1 == 0:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'samples1' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Wouldn't just one function be simpler here?

Comment: The error doesn't seem to have occurred in the code shown.

Comment: So where do you define `samples1`?

Comment: You are not passing any arguments to `fun_averaged()`.

Comment: Read [What limitations have closures in Python compared to language X closures?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/141642)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing:

```
while not num_samples == 0:
    totalave = fn(*args) + totalave
    num_samples -= 1
```

into:

```
for _ in range(num_samples):
    totalave = fn(*args) + totalave
```

Should help. You can access `num_samples` from the outer function but you cannot assign to it with `+=`.

I do **not** recommend it for this case, but in Python 3 you can use [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=nonlocal#nonlocal) to actual do what you intend:

```
nonlocal num_samples
while not num_samples == 0:
    totalave = fn(*args) + totalave
    num_samples -= 1
```

It works for the first call of `fun_averaged`. But the next time you call `fun_averaged` the value of `num_samples` will be `0`.

Comment: I have to use outer function? I thought "fun_averaged(*args)" will search the value of "num_samples" in "make_averaged" because it live inside of  "make_averaged"

Comment: It can see and use it, but it cannot assigned to it. As soon as you use `+=` it considers `num_samples` a local variable.

Comment: Actually,it can not be used in outer function too.I can only use nonlocal