# How do variable work inside a lambda function?

Tags: python, lambda, pyqt5, python-3.6

I am trying to connect 9 different buttons to one handler using a lambda function and some PyQt5 QPushButtons in python 3.6. If I assign them individually using ints all works fine. However if I try to use a list and a loop they are all assigned to a button number of 10. I can't understand why, since I would have thought that my assignment was to the integer value and that my variable was out of scope. Clearly, there is something I don't understand going on here. Can anyone explain the behavior of this code?

```
    self.buttonList = [ self.sq1Button,
                        self.sq2Button,
                        self.sq3Button,
                        self.sq4Button,
                        self.sq5Button,
                        self.sq6Button,
                        self.sq7Button,
                        self.sq8Button,
                        self.sq9Button]
    buttonNumber = 1
    for button in self.buttonList:
        button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.squareButtonHandler(buttonNumber))
        buttonNumber += 1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141642/what-limitations-have-closures-in-python-compared-to-language-x-closures If you look at this question it seems that typical python closures are read-only. A closure being a lambda that references a variable from outside it's scope.

Comment: You can think of it as being similar to being an object that takes a parameter, but instead of having an explicit constructor, it's implicit with a lambda.

Comment: @Novaterata - interesting, but they are not necessarily read-only. If some other inner function uses `nonlocal buttonNumber`, it can change the value for everybody.

Comment: Yes, that appears to be a new addition to the language to allow read/write closures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When python executes a function, it creates a namespace to hold local variables. The lambda in

```
button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.squareButtonHandler(buttonNumber))
```

is an inner function that contains a reference to `buttonNumber` in the outer scope. When you pass that lambda to `button.clicked.connect`, python has to remember that reference somehow. It does that by adding the context of the outer scope to the function object that it creates and passes to `connect`. The function objects for all of the buttons you connected referene the same outer context and that means they will all see whatever is in `buttonNumber` when the function exits.

Here is a running example showing your problem

```
def buttonHandler(num):
    print('button', num)

def try_lambda():
    handlers = []
    for num in range(5):
        handlers.append(lambda: buttonHandler(num))
    return handlers

print("test 1")
for handler in try_lambda():
    handler()
```

It produces

```
test 1
button 4
button 4
button 4
button 4
button 4
```

Yep, that's the problem. Lets take a look at the function objects we created by looking at the function object's closure

```
print("test 2")
for handler in try_lambda():
    handler()
    print(handler, handler.__closure__)
```

It shows

```
test 2
button 4
<function try_lambda.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f66e34a9d08> (<cell at 0x7f66e49fb3a8: int object at 0xa68aa0>,)
button 4
<function try_lambda.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f66e34a9d90> (<cell at 0x7f66e49fb3a8: int object at 0xa68aa0>,)
button 4
<function try_lambda.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f66e34a9e18> (<cell at 0x7f66e49fb3a8: int object at 0xa68aa0>,)
button 4
<function try_lambda.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f66e34a9ea0> (<cell at 0x7f66e49fb3a8: int object at 0xa68aa0>,)
button 4
<function try_lambda.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f66e349a048> (<cell at 0x7f66e49fb3a8: int object at 0xa68aa0>,)
```

Interesting. We got 4 different function objects (0x7f66e34a9d08, etc...) but a single cell holding the variable we want at 0x7f66e49fb3a8. That's why they all see the same number - they all use the same saved cell from the outer function's local variables.

In your case, `partial` is a better option. It creates a function using a variable's *current* value and works likes you want.

```
import functools

def try_partial():
    handlers = []
    for num in range(5):
        handlers.append(functools.partial(buttonHandler, num))
    return handlers

print("test 3")
for handler in try_partial():
    handler()
```

It produces

```
test 3
button 0
button 1
button 2
button 3
button 4
```

Comment: An option without `partial` is to make `num` local with `handlers.append(lambda num=num: buttonHandler(num))`.

Comment: I had used this once before. A friend gave me the code, but I don't think I really understood it fully. Now thanks to tdelaney, I believe I do! Thanks!
However, when I tried to keep the lambda by creating a local variable, it only worked if I used (lambda checked, num=num: buttonHandler(num)). I copied this from the code I was given, but I'm clueless as to what the "checked," bit is doing...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem once and [this](http://tobyho.com/2011/11/02/callbacks-in-loops/) helped me. What you basically need to do is move the click handler to a separate function and call the function with the `buttonNumber` from inside the loop. This is probably due to how closures work and/or because it needs a new `buttonNumber` every time the loop runs. I still don't understand the exact reason so if anyone does, please comment/edit.