# Fibonacci numbers with memoization runs slow in Python?

Tags: python

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 0
    if n == 2:
        return 1
    return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)


def memo(f):
    cache = {}
    def memoized(n):
        if n not in cache:
            cache[n] = f(n)
        return cache[n]
    return memoized

fib1 = memo(fib)
```

This code runs really slow on my laptop,
but if I change the name fib1 to fib, then everything works fine...anyone know the reason ? Thanks!

Comment: Add some prints to your fib() function and see if the calls make sense to you.

Comment: A nice way to do this is with decorators: http://ujihisa.blogspot.com/2010/11/memoized-recursive-fibonacci-in-python.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fib` recurses into `fib`, not `fib1`. If the memoized version has a different name it won't get used.

Answer (score 2):

In that code `fib` is the name of the non-memoized function. `fib1` is the name you've given to the memoized function. But if you see your code, you'll see that it recursively calls `fib` the non-memoized version. Hence why you aren't getting a speed advantage.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that adding some prints you would probably see the issue. You're very close to actually getting it.

What you have right now only stores n where n is the argument given to fib1. Inside fib, you're calling fib which won't memoize any previously computed values. So by adding a print statement to fib `print "fib ", n` and calling fib1(4), you will get the following output:

> fib  4
>   fib  2
>   fib  3
>   fib  1
>   fib  2

So you see it calls fib with n=2 twice. The reason why `fib = memo(fib)` is faster is because then it's actually momoizing because you're redefining fib to be the memoized function.

Answer (score 1):

In python 3 you can achieve your goal by using nonlocal [as pointed out here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857/can-you-explain-closures-as-they-relate-to-python/24061#24061).

```
def memo(f):
    cache = {}
    def memoized(n):
        nonlocal cache
        if n not in cache:
            cache[n] = f(n)
        return cache[n]
    return memoized
```

Python's functools module provides decorators that accomplish caching.  There is a limit to these approaches in that they add cost to the total recursion depth.  An alternate approach using closures allows for deeper recursion.

```
def fibonacci(n):
    cache = {0:0,1:1}
    def fib(n):
        if n in cache:
            return cache[n]
        cache[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
        return cache[n]
    return fib(n)
```