# Scope of variables in function factories

Tags: python, scope, factory

I was wondering about the scope of the variable `a` in the following Python snippet,

```py
# ============================
def get_plotter():
    def get_a():
        return a
    a = 3.14
    return get_a
# ============================
if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = get_plotter()
    print f()
# ============================
```

The output is `3.14`, but looking at the code I would have expected `a` to go out of scope as soon as `get_plotter()` terminates, effectively leaving an undefined something.

Is it just volatile memory contents that are printed here? What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works because of closures, or "functions with data attached", and is explained well here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/141426/735204