# How to properly iterate with re.sub() in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to make a Python script that creates footnotes. The idea is to find all strings of the sort `"Some body text.{^}{Some footnote text.}"` and replace them with `"Some body text.^#"`, where `"^#"` is the proper footnote number. (A different part of my script deals with actually printing out the footnotes at the bottom of the file.) The current code I'm using for this is:

```
pattern = r"\{\^\}\{(.*?)\}"
i = 0
def create_footnote_numbers(match):
   global i
   i += 1
   return "<sup>"+str(i)+"</sup>"

new_body_text = re.sub(pattern, create_footnote_numbers, text)
```

This works fine, but it seems weird to have to declare a variable (`i`) outside the `create_footnote_numbers` function and then have to call it inside that function. I would have thought there'd be something inside `re` that would return the number of the match.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Any callable can be used, so you could use a class to track the numbering:

```
class FootnoteNumbers(object):
    def __init__(self, start=1):
        self.count = start - 1

    def __call__(self, match):
        self.count += 1
        return "<sup>{}</sup>".format(self.count)


new_body_text = re.sub(pattern, FootnoteNumbers(), text)
```

Now the counter state is contained in the `FootnoteNumbers()` instance, and `self.count` will be set anew each time you start a `re.sub()` run.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Why do you have `start=` in your `def __init__()`? Why not just omit that and then make `self.count = 1` in the `__init__()`? Apologies if this is a stupid question --- I'm still trying to figure out how classes work in Python.

Comment: @Alan: Now you can do `FootnoteNumbers(10)` and your first footnote will be given that number. It is a nice extra bit of flexibility; you can omit that if you want to.

Comment: Done. Question: what are the principles behind editing StackExchange questions (like you did to mine)? Or, to ask it another way, how I can ask StackExchange questions in proper format, so that experienced members like you don't need to do after-the-fact editing?

Comment: A good guideline can be found in [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009); generally speaking, [Meta] clarifies and expands on the [FAQ].

Answer (score 6):

It seems like a good fit for [a closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13857/4279):

```
def make_footnote_counter(start=1):
    count = [start - 1] # emulate nonlocal keyword
    def footnote_counter(match):
        count[0] += 1
        return "<sup>%d</sup>" % count[0]
    return footnote_counter

new_body_text = re.sub(pattern, make_footnote_counter(), text)
```

Comment: But wouldn't `make_footnote_counter` reset `count` to `[start - 1]` every time it was called (since we're defining it inside `make_footnote_counter`)? Why wouldn't this just give me `<sup>1</sup>` every time? It's possible I just understand how closures work. Thanks.

Comment: @Alan: `re.sub()` calls `footnote_counter` function that is returned by a single `make_footnote_counter()` call. `count` is preserve between calls to `footnote_counter`. Follow the link in the answer to see other examples.

Answer (score 4):

A variation and Python-3-only solution:

```
def make_create_footnote_numbers(start=1):
    count = start - 1
    def create_footnote_numbers(match):
        nonlocal count
        count += 1
        return "<sup>{}</sup>".format(count)
    return create_footnote_numbers

new_body_text = re.sub(pattern, make_create_footnote_numbers(), text)
```