# passing object to object

Tags: python, object

I am trying to understand the background of why the following works:

```
def part_string(items):
    if len(items) == 1:
        item = items[0]
        def g(obj):
            return obj[item]
    else:
        def g(obj):
            return tuple(obj[item] for item in items)
    return g

my_indexes = (2,1)
my_string = 'ABCDEFG'
function_instance = part_string(my_indexes)
print(function_instance(my_string))
# also works: print(part_string(my_indexes)(my_string))
```

how come I can pass *my_string* to *function_instance* object even though I already passed *my_indexes* attributes to *part_string()* when creating *function_instance*? why Python accepts *my_string* implicitly?

I guess it has something to do with the following, so more questions here:
what is **obj** in *g(obj)*? can this be something other e.g. *g(stuff)* (like with *self* which is just a convention)?
what if I want to pass 2 objects to *function_instance*? how do I refer to them in *g(obj)*?

Can You recommend some reading on this?

Comment: See [Can you explain closures (as they relate to Python)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857/can-you-explain-closures-as-they-relate-to-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're encountering is a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).

When you write `part_string(my_indexes)` you're creating a new function, and upon calling it, you use the old variables you gave to `part_string` together with the new variables given to `function_instance`.

You may name the inner function whatever you want, and there is no convention. (`obj` is used in here but it can be `pie`. There are no conventions for this except `func` for function closures ([decorators](http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/)).

If you wish to pass two variables to the function, you may define two variables to the `g(obj)` function:

```
def g(var1, var2):
    ...
```

Here's some more info regarding [closures in python](http://www.shutupandship.com/2012/01/python-closures-explained.html).