# inner function accessing outer function's variable

Tags: python

Let's suppose to have this simple code:

```
def my_outer_function():
    outer_var = 123
    def my_inner_function():
        return outer_var + 1
    return my_inner_function

get_inner = my_outer_function()
get_inner()
```

I wonder there isn't any kind of runtime error. `outer_var` - the variable of the outer function - is available only when that function is running on, i.e. it vanishes when `my_outer_function` ends. But when I call `get_inner()`, `my_outer_function()` is already ended so I would have bet on a runtime error since `my_inner_function` couldn't find `outer_var`.

How do you explain all this?

Comment: Its called a [closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857/can-you-explain-closures-as-they-relate-to-python).

Comment: This is called a "closure". When you return the inner function, it captures the binding of the outer variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the variable of the outer function is available only when that function is running on, i.e. it vanishes when my_outer_function ends.

That's not entirely true. The variable is available in `my_outer_function`'s scope. `my_inner_function` has the scope of its own declarations *and* its parent's scope.

`my_inner_function` references a variable outside of its own scope, and so those references are bound to `my_inner_function` as a closure when its parent's scope is no longer available. To learn more about closures, see [Can you explain closures (as they relate to Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857/can-you-explain-closures-as-they-relate-to-python) (taken from Paul Rooney's comment)