# How does Lambda function works in this code?

Tags: python, lambda

I am learning Python from a site and there they have mentioned these lines of code for explaining lambda function

```
def first_number(n):
    return lambda first : first * n
    
second_num = first_number(2)

print(second_num(20))
```

Output is 40

How come that the code prints 40 and what values will be taken for variables 'first' and 'n', can anyone please explain this.

Comment: `first_number(2)` returns a functions. You then call this function with the value `20`. The returned function calculates `2 * 20`. What part exactly confuses you? Did you try to read about lambdas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are Python lambdas useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to briefly explain how this code works in your case:
When assigning `first_number(2)` to `second_num` on this line:

```
second_num = first_number(2)
```

you called the function `first_number` and replaced `n` with 2. The result is assigned to `second_num`.

Now, the function `first_number` doesn't just return a value like a constant: it returns a function, because `lambda` is a function with no name (read further about how lambda works) and you just replaced `n` with `2` and assigned that function to `second_num`.

A function returning a function... kinda weird and cool at the same time don't you think? ;)

So you could say that this line:

```
second_num = first_number(2)
```

actually becomes (or you could at least interpret it this way):

```
def second_num(first):
    return first * 2 #the 2 you passed in first_number
```

So after running `second_num(20)`, it returns 40, obviously.

**So what is lambda:**

As told, lambda is an unnamed function, so a function with no name. You could interpret this line:

```
lambda first: first * n
```

as a function like:

```
def thisisafunction(first):
    return first*n
```

So right after `lambda` are the parameters, comma-separated. And after the colon `:` is the body of the function.

Another way of applying lambda functions is to save some code. Like Python's `filter` function (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter), which asks for a function as a parameter. It saves you quite some code this way:

```
numbers_list = [2, 6, 8, 10, 11, 4, 12, 7, 13, 17, 0, 3, 21]

filtered_list = list(filter(lambda num: (num > 7), numbers_list))

print(filtered_list)
```

vs

```
numbers_list = [2, 6, 8, 10, 11, 4, 12, 7, 13, 17, 0, 3, 21]

def filterfunction(num):
    return num > 7

filtered_list = list(filter(filterfunction, numbers_list))
    
print(filtered_list)
```

Hopefully this makes things clear!

Comment: Thanks @Erik for our reply, can you explain as how does the variables take the values?

Comment: Could you be more specific what you mean with how it takes the variables? You could see `n` as a placeholder, you need to replace it with an actual value. The `first` variable is an actual argument. So the parameter you pass into the function is `first`!

Comment: @venkatramanBalasubramanian guess I understood your question. Updated my answer, hopefully this makes stuff clear.

Comment: I understood now that your first point "first_number(2)" returns lambda function to "second_num". I hope it sets 'n' as 2 and it will not change till the program execution gets over.


Even I was little confused about the second point, but that is also cleared, thanks a lot @Erik

Comment: You're absolutely welcome. Glad it cleared things up!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at just the lambda

```py
lambda first : first * n
```

Is equivalent to a function:

```py
def fn(first):
    return first * n
```

`first` is the argument, then it returns the result of the expression after the colon. The `n` comes from the closure which is not lambda specific.

Answer (score 0):

`n` is `2` and `first` is `20`. Notice that

```
def first_number(n):
    return lambda first : first * n
```

is a function that itself returns a function ([functions are first-class objects in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/first-class-functions-python/))! Thus

```
second_num = first_number(2)
```

is the rough equivalent of

```
def second_num(first):
    return first * 2
```

where the `n` from inside the first function's execution time is fixed to `2` and still accessible as a [closure variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857/can-you-explain-closures-as-they-relate-to-python).

Answer (score 0):

```
def first_number(n):
    return lambda first : first * n
```

is similar to

```
def first_number(n):
    def lambda_fuc(first):
        return first * n
    return lambda_fuc
```

so,

```
second_num = first_number(2)  ==> means n=2
print(second_num(20))         ==> means first=20
```

is similar to

```
def first_number(n=2):
    def lambda_fuc(first=20):
        return first * n
    return lambda_fuc
```

we get 40