# calculate weighted_average of pandas df in a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

I have a function and in this function I would like to calculate the weighted average of the column `other_column` (weighted with column `amount`). If I did not have this in a function then it would work, but like this I am not sure how to pass the dataframe? I'm also getting an error: `NameError: name 'df1' is not defined`.

```
def weighted_mean(x):
    try: 
        return np.average(x, weights=df1.loc[x.index, 'amount']) > 0.5
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0

def some_function(df1=None):
    df1 = df1.groupby('id').agg(xx=('amount', lambda x: x.sum() > 100),
                                yy=('other_col', weighted_mean)).reset_index()
    return df1

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,2,3], 'amount':[10, 200, 1, 10, 150], 'other_col':[0.1, 0.6, 0.7, 0.2, 0.4]})
df2 = some_function(df1=df2)
```

so that I get

```
   id     xx    yy
0   1   True    True
1   2   False   False
2   3   True    False
```

Comment: Why are you using `> 100` and `> 0.5` in your functions? Are some values to be excluded from the calculation of the weighted average?

Comment: that are the values I want to calculate. I just need a weighted sum to get there.

Comment: Please, explain how the expected output is calculated.

Comment: yy is just the weighted average of other_column with amount. So for id=1 you would have (10*0.1+200*0.6) /(10+200)  (which is 0.57 and this is larger than 0.5 and thus True). For id=2 you would do the same (0.7*1+0.2*10)/(1+10) (which is 0.24 and thus smaller than 0.5 and therefore False)

Comment: The above works if I don't write it in a function. But when I write it in a function it does not know which dataframe is referred.  So this I dont know how to write

Comment: The function will work if you define it after df1 is defined. But it's better practice to just pass df1 into the function as an argument.

Comment: I'm struggling a bit there. How do I write it in some_function then? Could you maybe amend the two functions and pass df1 as an argument?

Comment: df1 is local to `some_function` and not available to `weighted_mean.` If you simply change to `weights=df2.loc[x.index, 'amount']` instead of using df1 you will get the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fundamental issue is that you try to apply a [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with a function that relies on multiple columns. That's impossible, unless you rely on side effects, which cannot allow a general function (the function must be designed to hardcode the side effect).

```
# the function is hardcoded to use df2
# this makes it non generic
def weighted_mean(x):
    try: 
        return np.average(x, weights=df2.loc[x.index, 'amount']) > 0.5
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0
```

Instead, use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) and rewrite your function to take a DataFrame as input:

```
def weighted_mean(df):
    try: 
        return np.average(df['other_col'], weights=df['amount']) > 0.5
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0

def some_function(df=None):
    def inner(g):
        return pd.Series({
            'xx': g['amount'].sum()>100,
            'yy': weighted_mean(g),
        })
    
    return (df.groupby('id', as_index=False)
              .apply(inner)
            )

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,2,3],
                    'amount':[10, 200, 1, 10, 150],
                    'other_col':[0.1, 0.6, 0.7, 0.2, 0.4]})

out = some_function(df=df2)
```

Alternatively, define `weighted_mean` as an inner function of `some_function`:

```
def some_function(df=None):
    def weighted_mean(x):
        try: 
            return np.average(x, weights=df.loc[x.index, 'amount']) > 0.5
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            return 0
   
    return (df.groupby('id')
              .agg(xx=('amount', lambda x: x.sum() > 100),
                                yy=('other_col', weighted_mean))
              .reset_index()
            )

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,2,3],
                    'amount':[10, 200, 1, 10, 150],
                    'other_col':[0.1, 0.6, 0.7, 0.2, 0.4]})

out = some_function(df=df2)
```

Output:

```
   id     xx     yy
0   1   True   True
1   2  False  False
2   3   True  False
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `weighted_mean` function is missing its `df1` parameter. To fix the problem, this solution uses a `closure` (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47981346/22552608)

```
def weighted_mean(df1):
    def inner_weighted_mean(x):
        try: 
            return np.average(x, weights=df1.loc[x.index, 'amount']) > 0.5
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            return 0
    return inner_weighted_mean

def some_function(df1=None):
    # Adjust the function to create a closure with the current df1
    weighted_mean_for_df1 = weighted_mean(df1)
    df1 = df1.groupby('id').agg(
        xx=('amount', lambda x: x.sum() > 100),
        yy=('other_col', weighted_mean_for_df1)
    ).reset_index()
    return df1

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3], 
    'amount': [10, 200, 1, 10, 150], 
    'other_col': [0.1, 0.6, 0.7, 0.2, 0.4]
})

df2 = some_function(df1=df2)
```

Output:

```
   id     xx     yy
0   1   True   True
1   2  False  False
2   3   True  False
```

Comment: that's not what I want though, I would like to get a dataframe not a scalar. I added the desired output to my question

Comment: Please, explain how the expected output is calculated.